# Creating controls on current form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to have a template form that will load setting from tables. For example i will have a master table with different form IDs and then a textbox table that will have a list of textboxes with what form ID they belong too, their position, their value, and etc. The issue is when i open the form in design mode the code doesn't run and if I try and set the view to design mode i get and error saying "you cant switch to a different view at this time" with a code of 2174. here is the code i am using right now, all the values are hard coded so i know i don't have any errors with the reading from the database or anything. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Load()
    
    loadSettings
    
End Sub

Private Sub loadSettings()
    Dim ctl As Access.Control

    On Error GoTo ERR_Line
        
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDesignView
        Set ctl = CreateControl(Me.Name, acTextBox, acDetail, , , 100, 100, 100, 100)
        ctl.Name = "txt1"
        ctl.Value = "test"
        DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdFormView)

ERR_Line:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " Error Number " & Err

End Sub
```

If i use a module with this code in it, it will go into design mode but gives a "Microsoft Access cant add, rename, or delet the control(s) you requested." error number 29054.

```
Option Compare Database

Sub loadSettings(frmName As String)
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim ctl As Access.Control

    On Error GoTo ERR_Line
        
        Set frm = Application.Forms(frmName)
        DoCmd.Close acForm, frmName
         
        DoCmd.OpenForm frmName, acDesign
        
        Set ctl = CreateControl(frmName, acTextBox, acDetail, , , 100, 100, 100, 100)
        ctl.Name = "txt1"
        ctl.Value = "test"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, frmName, acSaveYes
        DoCmd.OpenForm frmName, acNormal, , , , , "asdf"

ERR_Line:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " Error Number " & Err

End Sub
```

Comment: This sentence does not make sense to me: "when i open the form in design mode the code doesn't run and if I try and set the view to design mode". Try to explain it a different way.

Comment: sorry, if i open the form using the command "DoCmd.OpenForm 'form_name', acDesign" then the code behind the form doesn't run. if i just open it using   "DoCmd.OpenForm 'form_name'" and then in the code behind the form run ""DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDesignView" it say "you cant switch to a different view at this time" with a code of 2174.

Comment: I did not test it but my explanation would be that because you are first creating a control via code it cannot be displayed in design view afterwords. And I do not see the point doing it.

Comment: after more testing i removed the error trap and then from the help button on the error message got a popup that said "your organization's administrator turned off the services required to use this feature". I am the administrator and I don't remember turning anything off, do you know what service i would need to run this?

Comment: i also found that i can switch to layout view, but I still get the control error

Comment: Maybe just the wrong event. Try `Form_Open` . Usually on dynamic forms you don't create new controls. You allready have enough controls and only make them visible if needed, because you can't use design-view on accde's or in runtime